# IE8 CSS background image URL being reset to url("null")

Tags: css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, selectivizr

I have an issue at the moment where in IE8 my background-image properties in CSS files are being changed to url("null") instead of the original URL that's in there.

Not sure where to look, but I suspect it could be selectivizr or JQuery UI.

Anyone experience this problem before?

**EDIT:** 
Here's the CSS code

```
span.k-icon
{
    background-image: url('http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/Default/sprite.png');
}
```

**EDIT 2:** 
I removed selectivizr out of the equation, which solves the problem. So this is definitely something to do with selectivizr. 
Regards,
Jacques

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can create a live demo on http://jsfiddle.net - hard to tell you what might cause such problem

Comment: Are you useing `background: url('http://www.url.nl/picture.png')`? Please provide your CSS code.

Comment: Hi Ladineko, I've added the code sample for the specific CSS class that I'm dealing with. It's nothing fancy, that's why I'm quite certain it's a JavaScript library that's causing the issue

Comment: keaukraine: I tried creating the scenario in jsfiddle.net, but it works in there and I'm not sure how to recreate the local scenario perfectly. I also can't give you access to the staged website because of NDA restrictions. Anything else I could do to make this easier?

Comment: I've added more comments about selectivizr

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer. This is a limitation in Selectivizr.

You can't use CDNs or external assets with selectivizr, CSS files and the like must be hosted on the same domain and relative paths must be used.

Here's a post about it. http://bigredtin.com/2010/selectivizr-with-css-on-a-cdn/

Regards,
Jacques